# Ruby/Nokogiri xmlns and other extensions via xpath

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

In the code below I'm trying to pull '90000' element using an xpath, but Nokogiri returns nil

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rspec xmlns="URL1"
xmlns:add="URL2"> 

<node> 
<price add:cars="90000"/>
</node>
</rspec>
```

I try the command:

```
puts  root.xpath("//add:cars", "add" => "URL2")
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
Could you please help me, I'm new at Ruby and I have searched a lot but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add:cars` is an *attribute* of the `price` element, not an element itself. The syntax you want is:

```
root.xpath("//xmlns:price/@add:cars")
```

or possibly even just

```
root.xpath("//@add:cars")
```

if you want the `add:cars` attributes of all elements.

Note that since the namespaces are declared on the root, Nokogiri registers them automatically so you don’t need to include the mappings in your call to `xpath` (you will need to include them if your document is more complex with namespaces being declared on non-root elements). Also the default namespace is registered with the prefix `xmlns`, so you can use that in your XPath.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I have another question. Could you please tell me what should I do, if,for example, I had three "node" nodes and I wanted to extract only the third one's price ? I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Jack Really you should [ask a separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) rather than ask in comments like this. It this case it looks fairly simple though, you want something like `//xmlns:node[3]/xmlns:price/@add:cars`. The `[3]` specifies the third `node` node, and the rest is pretty much as before. If this isn’t what you’re after then open a new question – you’ll have more space to explain and format your problem and you’ll get a better response since more people will see it.

Comment: I just thought that I shouldn't ask a such a similar question separately. I' ll keep this in mind. Thank you very much for your immediate response !

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this :

```
require 'nokogiri'

@doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse <<-eotl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rspec xmlns="URL1"
xmlns:add="URL2"> 

<node> 
<price add:cars="90000"/>
</node>
</rspec>
eotl

@doc.remove_namespaces!
@doc.at_xpath('//price/@cars').text
# => "90000"
```

or(if you want to keep namespaces as it is, then use below)

```
@doc.at_xpath('//xmlns:price/@add:cars').text
# => "90000"
```

Read this tutorial : [*Searching an HTML / XML Document*](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for  the answer, but I really need to keep the namespaces because I have many nodes with the same name (car) in my code. Can I do something diffrent?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of letting Nokogiri use CSS when dealing with namespaces:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rspec xmlns="URL1"
xmlns:add="URL2"> 

<node> 
<price add:cars="90000"/>
</node>
</rspec>
'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.at('price', 'add')['add:cars']
# => "90000"
```